# Query to map value of a column in another table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table `emp` and `bu_source`. Now the `emp` table is such as

```
mail_id            first_name    pos      bu_name
sreekom@abc.xom    sreekom       abc      land_bu
sreekom@abc.xom    sreekom       abc      land_bu
simth @thought.com  smith        xyz      MEZC
```

`bu_source` - this table does the grouping of bu_name. Eg land_bu, aev_bu will be grouped to power corporation,  BEZC and MEZC will be grouped to Equity ventures.
so table structure is like :

```
 source_bu_name result_bu_name 
    land_bu        power corporation
    aev_bu         power corporation
    BEZC           Equity ventures
    MEZC           Equity ventures
```

I want a query which results to following :

```
mail_id            first_name    pos      bu_name result_bu_name 
sreekom@abc.xom    sreekom       abc      land_bu  power corporation
simth @thought.com  smith        xyz      MEZC      Equity ventures
```

I have created a query

```
SELECT 
mail_id             ,
First_Name      ,
pos      ,
Source_Bu_Name      , -- bu name 
result_bu_name 
From Emp
left join bu_source on Emp.BU_NAME = bu_source.SOURCE_BU_NAME;
```

But this is givig few empty columns for bu_name though the table has values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to

```
SELECT 
    e.mail_id             
    ,e.first_name      
    ,e.pos      
    ,e.bu_name       --bs.source_bu_name
    ,bs.result_bu_name  
FROM 
    Emp e
LEFT JOIN 
    bu_source bs
ON 
    e.bu_name = bs.source_bu_name;
```

Comment: not working. still cross multiplication is happening fetching abt 20000 rows

Comment: @sreekembose Did your emp table has duplicated rows like in your sample data? Then you should change to `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: no it does not... the bu_mapping table is causing the cross multiplication

Comment: @sreekembose you means `source_bu_name` may be duplicated? If `result_bu_name` is duplicated too, use `SELECT DISTINCT`. If not, then for 2 rows of duplicated `source_bu_name`, which `result_bu_name` do you want to show? Please explain more by edit your sample data and expected output.